# Most efficient way to ask users for days of the week and start/end time for each day?

Tags: dates, time, datetimepicker, range

I have a situation wherein I need to ask users on what day of the week an activity takes place. It can take place anywhere from 1-7 days, but for each day the user "activates", there must be a start and end time.

The best way I can think to accomplish this is: checkboxes that toggle on/off for days, and range slider with start and end times.

Does anyone have a pre-established solution, or examples in the wild of this kind of UI?

Answer (score 1):

This is how Microsoft Family Safety letting you configure time-limits for using the computer (for your child account). Checking the box toggles its configuration, user can drag mouse for multiple selection.

[image]

Comment: Sure, but I am only allowing a single start and end time for each day, which is much less complicated and probably doesn't necessitate a grid.

Comment: You can force this policy on the grid. I would like it better than using a check-box and slider combination.

Comment: Well, a grid with a forced policy as you said is essentially the same as 7 sliders stacked on top of each other with two endpoints each.